# Does the order of operands in a boolean matter?

Tags: java, boolean

Does the order of operands in a Boolean affect the order of evaluation? As an example can I rely on

```
String s = ...;
if (s != null && s.length() > 10) ...
```

I seem to remember that the Java language does not define order of evaluation and that a null value of `s` could cause a NPE. Is this still true (a) in principle and (b) in practice with the common Java implementations?

UPDATE:
I couldn't find the exact duplicate. It's interesting to see the differences of opinions in the answers and get a downvote for it - ah well!

Comment: Of course Java defines an order of evaluation: [JLS 15.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7)

Comment: _"Java language does not define order of evaluation"_ `[citation-needed]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it does matter and

> ... the Java language does not define order of evaluation

is not true. The arguments are evaluated from left to right, so an expression like `s != null && s.length() > 10` will never throw a `NullPointerException`.

See [15.7 Expressions - Evaluation Order](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7) in the Java Language Specification.

Comment: It's not that it's evaluated L-R, but that the 2nd operand is not evaluated if the 1st is false.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Both are relevant; if it wasn't L-R then short-circuiting would be meaningless.

Comment: The spec at least says: "the operands of operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order, namely, from left to right."

Answer (score 2):

No it is not true. This is the correct way to avoid null pointer exceptions. An operand is evaluated and the next one is evaluated only if the expression's value is still not clear.

This means that:

- if you have an and operator (&&) and the first operand evaluates to false the second one will not be evaluated.
- if you have an or operator (||) and the first operand evaluates to true the second one will not be evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

Java, and many other languages, support [Short Circuit Evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) of boolean statements.

## `&&` and `||`

In Java, `&&` and `||` are the short-circuit boolean operators. If you use these, the second argument will only be evaluated if its necessary to ascertain the truth value of the statement.

## `&` and `|`

In Java, the bitwise operators `&` and `|` are also non short-circuiting boolean operators. If they are used, both arguments will always be evaluated.

Comment: It's not that the bitwise operators are "eager boolean operators", it's that they're bitwise operators. They're not boolean operators at all.

Comment: @DaveNewton I saw them referred to in that way in a source that I can't currently find. Not the Java Lang Spec, so probably invalid. Corrected.

Comment: @DaveNewton: The Java `&` and `|` are either bitwise or logical operators, depending on the types of their operands.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yeah, this is true. I still have an issue with them being called "eager boolean operators", though. I could live with "non-short-circuiting", but there's nothing eager about them.

Answer (score 0):

It is called *short-circuit logical and operation*, meaning the part after `&&` will never be evaluated if the one before were to return `false`.

We have even *short-circuit logical or operation*, which doesn't evaluate the part after the `||` if the one before were to return `true`.

Such operands are typically used in `null` checks as in the example you posted.

If you were to do the below (normal and operator) with `s` being `null`, the result would be catastrophic.

```
if (s != null & s.length() > 10)
```

This is because `s.length()` will continue to be attempted to be evaluated even if `s != null` returns a `false`, leading to a `NullPointerException` on `s.length()`. With the short-circuit version, however, the second part will be completely skipped.

Comment: "the result would be catastrophic". That's an overdramatic statement without the useful accompanying explanation if I've ever heard one.

Comment: If you were referring to the fact that I didn't mention "with `s` being `null`", the answer has been edited now.

Comment: I'm referring to the fact that you didn't explain what `&` does that is different from `&&`.